# Multiple header rows being printed when writing with Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark SQL to load large CSV files and join them on a common column. After performing the join in my code, I'd like to save the table back to a new CSV file. I'm using DataFrame's `write()` method to do this. Upon inspection of the file, I was surprised to see the header printed out multiple times followed by the data, followed by more headers. For example:

```
name, age, addr, job, salary
name, age, addr, job, salary
name, age, addr, job, salary

Bob, 34, 123 Fake St, Programmer, 10000000
June, 23, 5 Tree Ave., College Student, 15000
Rick, 12, 43 Ware St., Student, 0

name, age, addr, job, salary
name, age, addr, job, salary
name, age, addr, job, salary

<more data here>
```

This output is unexpected, especially since the DataFrame class's `show()` method prints the table to console and displays what I'd expect.

The code I'm using to perform the write:

```
bigTable.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true").save(settings.getValue().outputDir  +"/bigTable.csv");
```

When using the setting `option("header", "false")` the data values are saved in the CSV correctly. Is this a bug?

Comment: what are the source csv files? how do you read them with spark-csv?

Comment: the reason @MiladKhajavi is asking is , if it's text files and you're looking at them with hadoop fs -text /my/dir/* you probably have multiple files in there, hence multiple headers.

Comment: @MiladKhajavi, I'm reading them with Spark SQL (specifically using Databricks' API). I am reading from several CSV files, but joining them together using Spark SQL dataframes. I'd expect that once they're joined, there would only be 1 header row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found a solution by using the `partition()` and `coalesce()` functions:

```
bigTable.repartition(1).coalesce(1).write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("myoutputfile.csv");
```

After adding these calls the CSV file has the output I'd expect.